# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight') using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Part of my code is to create a function to scroll the page. This is reproduced from the code to scrape Google Jobs [here](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-jobs-organic-results-with-python/)

It throws an error "javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight')"

I'm not sure why `document.querySelector('.zxU94d')` is null:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def scroll_page(url):
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
    # Add the settings to run the Chrome browser 
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--lang=en')
    options.add_argument("user-agent=AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Store the initial height of Google Jobs page
    old_height = driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollHeight")
```

When I go to the URL accessed manually ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=data+science+internship+usa&ibp=htl;jobs&hl=en&gl=us&fpstate=tldetail)), I can get the height on Console without problem.

If I tried handling null it will return NoneType:

```py
old_height = driver.execute_script("""
if (document.querySelector('.zxU94d')) {
    document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollHeight;
}
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the [Scrape Google Jobs organic results with Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-jobs-organic-results-with-python) blog you link to.

When writing the script, I ran into the same problem as you - the page height was not read. I solved this problem by declaring a function that returns the height of the page and calling it:

```py
old_height = driver.execute_script("""
    function getHeight() {
        return document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollHeight;
    }
    return getHeight();
""")
```

You are using the [`scrollHeight` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) to get the height of a certain element, it does not allow you to implement page scrolling. In order to scroll the page, use the [`scrollTo()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo).

If you need to scroll down the page only once, then you can add the following script:

```py
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollTo(0, document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollHeight)")
```

If you need to scroll the page to the end, then the algorithm looks like this:

1. Find out the initial page height and write the result to the `old_height` variable.
2. Scroll the page using the script and wait a few seconds for the data to load.
3. Find out the new page height and write the result to the `new_height` variable.
4. If the variables `new_height` and `old_height` are equal, then we complete the algorithm, otherwise we write the value of the variable `new_height` to the variable `old_height` and return to step 2.

```py
# 1 step
old_height = driver.execute_script("""
    () => document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollHeight;
""")

while True:
    # 2 step
    driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollTo(0, document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(2)

    # 3 step
    new_height = driver.execute_script("""
        () => document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollHeight;
    """)

    # 4 step
    if new_height == old_height:
        break

    old_height = new_height
```

If there are difficulties, I will be happy to answer all questions.

Answer (score 0):

When web scraping with Selenium it's best to wait for elements to load explicitly. In your case it's likely that your driver is executing the javascript before the page is fully loaded.

You can use `WebDriverWait` function:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

_timeout = 10  # seconds
WebDriverWait(driver, _timeout).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".zxU94d")
    )
)
old_height = driver.execute_script("""if (document.querySelector('.zxU94d')) {
                                           document.querySelector('.zxU94d').scrollHeight
                                       }""")
```

Comment: This is true but only for sites that add content after doc load (PWAs mostly). Any Google site should not need this

Answer (score 0):

what @granitosaurus said, but also forget about the if and use optional chain operator (?). Don't forget to "return" (very important)

```
old_height = driver.execute_script("""     
  return document.querySelector('.zxU94d')?.scrollHeight || 0
""")
```